# Docker and Kafka with MySQL Scripts deployment

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have a project based on a massive ingestion of Kafka messages, those messages interact with a MySQL database.

I want to know the best way to update MySQL tables using scripts (.sql). I'm thinking about deploy them during the application startup, then Kafka will save the messages until the application is started and send them to the application with all database modifications finished.
Any idea/example? I suppose kubernetes orchestration can be a problem to achieve this!

Comment: Can you explain the process more? Kafka records have a default limit of 1MB, and shouldn't be used to store "files" in any format, rather individual database records could be put in Kafka. But if you already have a mysql dump file, Kafka isn't needed

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer.As you said, it wasn't well explained here. It is better at this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628291/application-updating-db-scripts-and-entities-using-kubernetes-and-kafka)

Answer (score 1):

One theoretical possibility here sergio

- Attach the script to a PVC to be used in MySQL and add the scripts to
  run
- Use a post start hook and run the script mounted
  ([Post start hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/))
- For the kafka container have a
  [init-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). This checks for existance of a row or some
  check if all is well with the MySQL pod
- Bring up the kafka pod

(was over limit for a comment , posted as an answer)

Comment: Anyway, the MySQL update is joined to a project with the entities that should be updated too (this project is which has the kafka listener). I was thinking in something similar to what you said but, have two processes, one an old one consuming the last Kafka messages (and blocking the kafka listener to not read more) and another new one with the DB updates (entities), and consuming from Kafka the new messages.

Comment: Anyway I don't know if I can have a container running while I try to run another pod with the same container inside it. I want a container to finish gracefully and have both up during a period of time, until the old one finishes.