# Application updating DB Scripts and entities using Kubernetes and Kafka

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka

I have an application ingesting Kafka messages, that application interact with a MySQL database using entities that map the DB (so scripts modifications will have entities modifications). I want to know the best way to update entities from the application and MySQL tables using scripts (.sql) at the same time.

I'm thinking about deploying them during the application startup (as an init container 'UpdaterService'), Kafka will keep the messages until the new application container is started and send them begin to send them when all database modifications have finished. Anyway, I don't know if I can have two containers with the same name running until one finishes! and should I have Kafka sender in another pod to avoid it to be restarted?

[image]

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. If you used Kafka Connect, for example (make your app write to Kafka, then only Connect actually writes to the database), then you can have that auto-evolve the table, in a backwards compatible way. The only time to change your producer application is for Kafka record schema changes

Comment: Is another system which writes to Kafka, my application just reads from that kafka messaging producer. I'm thinking about stoping the kafka listener in my application to begin with DB updates. And not, I'm not using Kafka connect!

Comment: Okay, fine. What does that have to do with Kafka? Sounds like you'd have to stop _any_ database client, regardless, while you preform upgrades. Container "names" shouldn't matter either, but if you to prevent one from running until another finishes, sounds like you need a workflow engine like Airflow

Comment: Yes, it is a database client, I think I should have two containers initiated at different times running together until the older finishes). I expect to control the workflow with lifecycle hooks [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) and init containers [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

Comment: If your hooks directly communicate with the API-server, then I guess that would work, sure. Like I said, Airflow can do similar operations with Kubernetes operator https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html